# Explicit set of positive integers whose subsets of size 3 have unique sum

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, probabilistic-method

In a [recent Stack Overflow answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41417307/2144669), the hardness reduction that I outlined needs a set $U$ of $n$ positive integers such that, given two subsets $S,T\subseteq\binom U3$, if $\sum_{s\in S}s=\sum_{t\in T}t$, then $S=T$.

The obvious solution is $U:=\{2^k\mid k\in[n]\}$, where $[n]:=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, but then my reduction would only imply weak hardness due to the exponential size of the set members.

In my answer, I used the probabilistic method. Let $U:=\{u_k+1\mid k\in[n]\}$, where $(u_k)_{k\in[n]}\leftarrow[n^6]^n$ is chosen uniformly at random. When $n>3$, it suffices to verify that, for all $J,K\in\binom{[n]}3$, if $\sum_{j\in J}u_j=\sum_{k\in K}u_k$, then $J=K$, since the pairwise distinctness of the $u_k$ follows. There are $\binom{\binom n3}2<\frac{n^6}{12}$ pairs of $J,K$ to worry about, and each contributes a failure with probability less than $n^{-6}$, so the success probability is greater than $\frac{11}{12}$.

This suffices for a Las Vegas reduction, but NP-hardness reductions must be deterministic. Is there an effective polynomial-time construction that uses integers bounded by a polynomial in $n$? I'd also be interested in ways to reduce the polynomial exponent from $6$ (the obvious lower bound is $3$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is solvable with a symmetric polynomial reconstruction trick that I learned from [a paper by Eppstein and Goodrich](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3313).

Assuming that $n>3$, find a prime $p$ such that $n<p<2n-2$, whose existence is guaranteed by Bertrand's postulate. The solution below uses vectors in $\mathbb Z_p^3$ instead of integers. We interpret the vectors as three-digit numbers base $3p+1$, resulting in set elements that are $O(n^3)$.

Set $u_k:=(k\bmod p,\:k^2\bmod p,\:k^3\bmod p)$. We show that, from $u_a+u_b+u_c$, we can reconstruct $\{a,b,c\}$, which implies the uniqueness criterion. Given the sum, we know $p_1:=a+b+c$ and $p_2:=a^2+b^2+c^2$ and $p_3:=a^3+b^3+c^3$. We want to compute the polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, which encodes $\{a,b,c\}$ by the uniqueness of factoring polynomials over a field.

$$\begin{align*}
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)&=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+ac+bc)x-abc\\
&=x^3-p_1x^2+\frac{p_1^2-p_2}2x-\frac{p_1^3-3p_1p_2+2p_3}6
\end{align*}$$